# Kolmogorov forward equations and PDEs

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $$u(t, x) = \mathbb{E}{(f(x e^{W_{t}^{2}- \frac{1}{2}t}))}$$
whence $f$ is a twice continuously differentiable function such all its derivatives up to order $2$ are bounded.

I would like to find a partial differential equation such that $u := u(t, x)$ is the solution for the boundary value problem $$u(0, x) = f(x)$$.

For example, one can consider a simplier case: let $$u(t, x) = \mathbb{E}{(f(x+W_{t}))}$$

Since the $W_{t} \sim N(0, t)$, then
$$ u(t, x) = \mathbb{E}{(f(x+W_{t}))} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}{f(x+y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}t} e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2t}}dy}$$

Here we notice that the latter integral is the solution of the boundary value problem for the heat equation $$u_{t} = u_{xx}$$ with $$u(0, x) = f(x)$$.

My questions are:

(1) In order to proceed in the similar fashion one should understand, how does the distribution of $$X_{t} = e^{W_{t}^{2} - \frac{1}{2}t}$$ look like for a fixed $t$. Are there any simple ways to derive the latter? (i'm familiar with the brownian bridge, but that does not seem to be helpful though)

(2) One can use the Fokker-Plank-Kolmogorov equation that, endowed with the Ito formula, gives the result, but how one can derive the answer without applying a sort of 'overkilling' techniques?

Comment: I cannot come up with a PDE whose solution is $u(t,x)$ right now, but as far as writing down the density of $X_t$ is concerned, you can use the fact that $W_t^2$ has $\chi^2$-distribution with density given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution

Answer (score 1):

So, finally, seems as if i have figured out the right way to answer my question.
Let $X_{t} = e^{W_{t}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}t}$

(1)  *What can we say about the distribution of $X_{t}$?*

**Lemma**  If $$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$$ then $$aX+b \sim N(a\mu+v, a^{2} \sigma^{2})$$

(there are many ways to prove it, for example, using characteristic functions)

Since $W_{T} \sim N(0, T)$, then, applying the lemma, we obtain $$W_{T} - \frac{1}{2}T \sim N(-\frac{1}{2}T, T)$$

Finally, $e^{W_{T} - \frac{1}{2}T}$ is *log-normally* distributed with $\mu = -\frac{1}{2}T$ and $\sigma^{2} = T$

(2) *What can we say about $u(x, t)$*?

**The "high-tech" approach**

**Lemma**
Let $X_{t}$ be the solution of the SPDE
$$dX_{t} = \mu(X_{t}, t) dt + \sigma(X_{t}, t) dW_{t}$$
$$X_{0} = X$$

Then the function $u(t, x) = \mathbb{E}(f(X_{t}))$ is the solution of the following PDE

$$u_{t} = \mu(x, t) u_{x} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}(x, t) u_{xx}$$
$$u(x, 0) = f(x)$$

(this result based on a derivation of so-called Kolmogorov forward equation)

Thus, by Ito formula
$$dX_{t} = -\frac{1}{2}xe^{W_{t} - \frac{1}{2}t} dt + x e^{W_{t} - \frac{1}{2}t} dW_{t} + \frac{1}{2} x e^{W_{t}-\frac{1}{2}t} (dW_{t})^{2} = x e^{W_{t} - \frac{1}{2}t} dW_{t}$$
The latter means that $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = x$, thus, $u := u(t, x)$ is the solution of the following PDE
$$ u_{t} = \frac{1}{2}x^{2}u_{xx}$$
$$ u(0, x) = f(x)$$

**The low-tech approach**
Note that $$u := u(x, t) = \mathbb{E}(f(X_{t})) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}{f(x e^{y-\frac{1}{2}t}) e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{4t^{2}}}dy}$$

Under some mild conditions (we should be able to differentiate w.r.t the parameter under the integral sign) one can check that the function $u(x, t)$ indeed satisfy to the equation above.